# Correlate two variables in a CPLEX constraint

Tags: cplex

While working on a linear program, I came across this question: it is possible to correlate two classes of variables, for example Xij (set of variables greater than or equal to zero) and Yij (decision variables) so that:

```
if Xij> 0 -> Yij = 1
if Xij == 0 -> Yij = 0
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for my proposed solution to work, first, you need to define values `Xij_min` and `Xij_max` to represent the minimum and maximum limits of the `Xij` variable when it is `Xij > 0`.

`Xij_min` can be as small as you wish or makes sense and `Xij_max` can be arbitrarily high if there are no physical limits to your variables.

Then by adding the two following constraints, what you want can be achieved:

```
Xij >= Xij_min * Yij
Xij <= Xij_max * Yij
```

For the sake of this example, I will assume `Xij_min = 0.1` and `Xij_max = 1000`. This will make the constraints:

```
Xij >= 0.1 * Yij
Xij <= 1000 * Yij
```

If `Xij` is to take a value between 0.1 and 1000 (which we defined as the feasible, positive range), then `Yij` will have to be 1.

Now if `Xij` becomes 0, then in order for these constraints to hold `Yij` will need to be 0 in order to have `Xij <= 0` and `Xij >= 0`.

Comment: Thanks! Very smart solution

Answer (score 0):

With all CPLEX APIs you may use logical constraints.

For instance for "[if then](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=e2afa1ed-3afb-4b6e-b70e-dac047665ca1&ps=25)" in [OPL CPLEX](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/) you can write

```
int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;



dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;

minimize
 costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;

subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;

 // with if nb buses 40 more than 3  then nb buses30 more than 7

 (nbBus40>=3)=>(nbBus30>=7);
 //(nbBus40>=3)<=(nbBus30>=7); //equivalent
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I didn't know that conditional constraints could be used.